# XMLType in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I have the below code in SQL Server:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParseCapIQCurrency](
    @XMLString varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   --Validate proper xml format; SQL does not allow TRYCAST on xml.
   DECLARE @XML xml 
   BEGIN TRY
    SET @XML= Cast(@XMLString as xml)
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('XMLString not in XML format.',16,1)
    RETURN
   END CATCH

   DECLARE @CURRENCY_EXCHANGE table(StartDate date, Currency varchar(50), Rate float)

   DECLARE @TABLE table(Currency varchar(50), ExchangeRate float, XMLProps xml)   
   insert into @TABLE(Currency,ExchangeRate, XMLProps)
    select X.c.value('(Identifier)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Currency,
           X.c.value('(Body/Rows/Row/C_V)[1]','float') as ExangeRate,          
           X.c.query('Properties') as XMLProps
        from @XML.nodes('/SDKClientResponse/DataArea/MultiResponse/SingleResponse') as X(c)

  DECLARE @IXStartDate int=2
  select X.c.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as 'StartDate',
        Currency, 
        ExchangeRate        
    from @TABLE
        cross apply XMLProps.nodes('/Properties/Property[position()=(sql:variable("@IXStartDate"))]') as X(c)

END
```

I have to convert the above to PLSQL which i am finding extremely difficult as i am relatively new to Plsql and i dont seem to find much information on the xml data type topic.
Could anybody help on how to convert this?And is it possible to convert this?

Comment: Please edit your questionprovide an example xml document you want to pass in to the procedure, and the expected output. I'm assuming you're going to do something with the selected values?

Comment: Also, please note that SQL != SQL Server. SQL is a language, [Microsoft] SQL Server is a relational database management system (RDBMS).

Comment: What does this procedure do?

Comment: It looks like you just have a string value which you want to convert to XMLType and then pull data out relationally... so you might just want a simple `XMLTable()` query, rather than a procedure? Kind of hard to be sure without input and output though.